# Read json and print output in loop in FASTAPI?

Tags: json, fastapi

i wonder how to load json data in a variable to work with it.

`data = '{"name": "John Smith", "hometown": {"name": "New York", "id": 123}}'
x = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
print(x.versions.name)`

This above works, but when i try to get multiple things in it it breaks with errors.

`data1 = '{"versions": {"name": "123", "post": [{"thing1": "value", "thing2": "value2"}]}, {"name": "321", "post": [{"thing1": "value", "thing2": "value2"}]}'
x = json.loads(data1, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
print(x.versions.name[0])`

Do you guys know what iam doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Comment: please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you're going to have multiple entries, you'll have to define a list. You're just listing objects after each other: `"versions": {...}, {...}`. Wrap the inner objects inside `[]` to create a list: `"versions": [{...}, {...}}`. However, there's usually a better solution than handling JSON manually in FastAPI and Pydantic.